# Customize fonts inside an equation environment

Tags: beamer, fonts, xetex, fontspec

I am using the `Gill Sans` font, but I remark that I,l, and 1 are confused. So I want to use another fonts just for these letters in the equation environment, I used `\fontspec` to do this but it does not change the fonts inside the equation environment!.

My MWE (Compile with XeLaTeX):

```
  \documentclass{beamer}
     \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
     \usepackage{lmodern}
     \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
     \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
     \setmainfont{Gill Sans}    
      \setsansfont[ItalicFont={Gill Sans MT  Italic}]{Gill Sans}


     \newcommand{\vl}{\fontspec{BrushScript}{l}}%BrushScript for l
     \newcommand{\vI}{\fontspec{Courier BOLD}{I}} % Courier BOLD for I
     \newcommand{\un}{\fontspec{Courier BOLD}{1}} % Courier BOLD for 1
    \begin{document}


    \begin{frame}{}
       \fontspec{Gill Sans}{(l,I,1)}, \vl, \vI,\un. In the equation environment:
               \begin{equation*}
                   \vl, \vI,\un 
              \end{equation*}   


    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

which gives:
[image]

Comment: The observation "this does not work!" is not very specific. What exactly isn't working? Do you get error and/or warning messages? If so, what do the say? And, where might the font named `BrushScript` be obtained from?

Comment: @Mico thanks for your comment, I meant it does not change the font of the symbols. I have all the fonts instaled

Comment: I'm afraid that the font name `BrushScript` isn't installed on my system; that's why I asked where one might obtain it from. Is it a free font?

Comment: @Mico, I think that It is not free. But you can use any other font since the idea is how to specify a font inside the equation environment?. N.B: I added a printed image of the compiled MWE

Comment: Many math fonts provide the macro `\ell`, which generates a script/curvy `l` ("ell"). `\ell` is often used if the math-mode "l" ("ell") could be confused with "I" (cap-eye) and `1` (one).

Comment: @Mico, That's why I want to use the `l` (Lower case L) from `BrushScript` font.

Comment: Do you need **fontenc** or **lmodern**? And don't you need to tell Beamer you are doing your own font configuration? I don't quite understand what you want to do, mind, since you tell **fontspec** not to mess with maths, which presumably means you want **lmodern**'s config, but then you want to use Gill Sans inside `equation` environments but not other maths environments?

Comment: @cfr , I just found **fontec** and **lmodern** in the preamble of the beamer template and  honestly, I do not understand their roles.

Comment: @cfr, It does not work when I comment these packages too :( .

Comment: I didn't mean that commenting them out would solve the problem but they do not make sense. As I say, I don't really understand what you are trying to do. You need `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` regardless, but beyond that it is hard to say.

Comment: @cfr, I want to keep the font the same as in the MWE and use `BrushScript` font  only for  `l` (Lower case L) in the equations. I remark that `professionalfonts` has letters which are more thick than what I has in my MWE.

Comment: Without that, Beamer overrides your font configuration. If you like its choices, that's fine. But you are probably not using the fonts you think.

Comment: @cfr, good, and then how I can specify the `BrushScript`  font for Lower case L?

Comment: I guess you do need `lmodern` to get traditional maths in Latin Modern rather than CM. It seems odd that **fontspec** switches text without using matching maths, but that is what it seems to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `professionalfonts` theme if using your own configuration to avoid unexpected weirdnesses cropping up at inconvenient moments.

You do not need **fontenc** as far as I can tell.

You ***do*** need **lmodern** because otherwise the default maths will still use Computer Modern, even though **fontspec** switches text to Latin Modern.

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do. If you want to be able to use a text character in maths mode without needing to switch explicitly to text, you can use `\text{}` from **amsmath** inside the definition of your macros.

Note that `\fontspec{}[]` takes one mandatory and one optional argument. It does not take a second mandatory argument and the second set of brackets in your definitions do nothing.

So

```
\fontspec{<font name>}[<options>] <whatever>
```

However, it is better to define an additional font family than to keep using `\fontspec` for the same font/settings.

```
\newfontfamily\tgschola{TeXGyreSchola}
\newfontfamily\helvetica{Helvetica Neue}
```

I don't have the fonts you are using here so I've substituted ones I do. Then we can say something like this

```
\newcommand*{\vl}{\text{\tgschola\textit{l}}}
\newcommand*{\vI}{\text{\helvetica I}}
\newcommand*{\un}{\text{\helvetica 1}}
```

The `\text{}` ensures the switch to text mode.

The output then looks as follows

[image: text characters in maths mode]

But note that if these are mathematical characters, this probably is not the solution you want and you should define them as maths symbols or whatever instead.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{lmodern,amsmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Gill Sans}
\setsansfont[ItalicFont={Gill Sans Italic}]{Gill Sans}
\newfontfamily\tgschola{TeXGyreSchola}
\newfontfamily\helvetica{Helvetica Neue}
\newcommand*{\vl}{\text{\tgschola\textit{l}}}
\newcommand*{\vI}{\text{\helvetica I}}
\newcommand*{\un}{\text{\helvetica 1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
  (l,I,1), \vl, \vI,\un. In the equation environment:
  \begin{equation*}
    \vl, \vI, \un
  \end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @cfc, Thanks a lot , this is exactly what I wanted !  .

Comment: @cfc, Have you any idea about how to make for example $\alpha$ as heavy as the latine letters ?

Comment: You need to pick a font for maths which works with the text font you are using. Right now, you are using Latin Modern for maths symbols. Probably that may not be a good choice to accompany Gill Sans.

Comment: @cfc, how I can pick it ?. Any suggestions for appropriate math fonts are so appreciated.

Comment: Maybe start with http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html. Or you can use an opentype maths font, but there are not that many available.

Comment: Thanks for the link, what is the command by which I can choose a font?

Comment: Click on the link for more information about the font you're interested in, including relevant code. It will also tell you the package name so you can look up the documentation for further information.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I picked  the **Computer Concrete** font, and to use it only for the math I comment `\setmainfont{Gill Sans}` and added `\usepackage{concmath}
\renewcommand\rmdefault{Gill Sans} `